# проблема с подсчетом

Tags: mysql

```
$count = DB :: $dbs -> querySingle("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `mail` WHERE `id_users` = '".$mail['usersSend']."' AND `id_contact` = '".App::user()->id."' ORDER BY `read` = 0 ",0);
```

Должно показывать 0 сообщений, а показывает 6, хотя у всех сообщений флаг read = 1, тоесть они прочтены.
В чем беда?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AND `read` = '0' ночь. ех)      .